# Easter Egg Hunt

Tags: mathematics, wordplay

Somebunny hid some eggs in my yard! Can you help me find them?

I woke up this morning and my yard was a mess. Last night I saw lots of bunnies out there, doing what bunnies do, and all of the bunnies were black or white. Now my yard looks like this:

```
365.1435
1.523007
237.2203
107.4861
0565.899
131.3877
057.8623
1.458747
```

How many eggs are hidden in my yard?
This puzzle was brought to you by the letter ____

**Hint:**

> All of the numbers in my yard are integers.

**Hint 2:**

> A child could solve this puzzle with a calculator, if you showed her what operations to perform on the yard.

Since apparently this was harder than I thought, **Really Big Hint 3:**

> I already told you what two operations to perform on the yard, and in what order.

Comment: math not geography?

Comment: @Raystafarian - correct.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have

> 22 eggs.

Reasoning:

> *doing what bunnies do* would be another way of saying *multiplying*.
>  All of the bunnies are black or white, so we should probably interpret the results as binary.
>  Multiplying both of the integers in each line, then printing the result in binary form gives:
>
> ```
> 1111111110111111111
> 1111111101011111111
> 1111111011101111111
> 1111110111110111111
> 1111100000000011111
> 1111011111111101111
> 1110111111111110111
> 1101111111111111011
> ```
>
> Which, interpreting a 0 to look like an egg, gives 22 eggs in total.
>  This puzzle was brought to you by the letter A, and the numbers 1 and 0.

Comment: Somebunny finally figured it out.